# How to authenticate user logging in with twitter using token

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement twitter login into my application, I obtain the oauth_token from twitter using socialite then I followed the steps at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/authenticate

and I pass the token of the user to this URL: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=some_token

but it always gives me "The request token for this page is invalid".

Comment: Verify with the twitter documentation or search for already functional PHP solution or laravel package.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel,

You Can Use **Socialite**

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/socialite